# Is it possible to get navigation 1.10.1?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i am a beginner and is using the navigation stack for my school project. The function that I am interested in is the base_local_ planner. On its [web page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner) section 4 generic local planning, it is mentioned that it is possible to create custom local planner. However, this is only for release 1.10.1. But I can't get navigation 1.10.1, even after running apt-get update. (mine is 1.8.3, after checking the Cmakelist). May i know if navigation 1.10.1 is out yet? If so how can i get it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44830/is-it-possible-to-get-navigation-1.10.1?/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2012-09-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The nav stack did change in that respect, so if you can, you should use the new code.
The new classes as shown on that wiki page make it easier for you to create a custom local planner.

You can use the sources for 1.9/1.10 with ros 1.8 as well, the APIs did not change.

And to get it, just download the sources.

```
$ hg pull https://kforge.ros.org/navigation/navigation
```

will get you the sources, if you use rosws, you can do

```
$ roslocate info navigation 
- hg:
    local-name: navigation
    meta:
      repo-name: rosdistro_fuerte
    uri: https://kforge.ros.org/navigation/navigation
    version: navigation-1.8
```

Copy this to your rosinstall file replacing version navigation-1.8 with navigation-1.9.1

Another way to do this is to call

```
$ rosws set navigation --hg https://kforge.ros.org/navigation/navigation --version=navigation-1.9.1
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-10-05**:
Thank you. Let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What's wrong with using 1.8.3? Did you try it? I think the nav stack didn't really change so using the current version shouldn't be a problem.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-09-30**:
No. 1.8.3 is working fine. Just that on the web page, it is mentioned that the generic local planning is new in 1.10.1. So if i want to create a custom local planner, is it possible to do so on 1.8.3?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-09-30**:
Sure. It should work in 1.8.3, too.

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/3058/chengxiang/) on 2012-09-30**:
Thanks. i will try it out.